# pandas data filtring typeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi guyss i was doing practice filter of data with pandas but I got bug. i was just wondering I did same thing for both line but one of them is working. i got bug for other one .

- this one is working

```
result = df[df["Movie Rating"] >= 8.5][["Movie Name","Movie Rating"]].head(300)
```

- this one is not working

```
result = df[(df["Year of Release"] >= (1960)) & (df["Year of Release"] <= (2000))][["Movie Name","Year of Release"]]
```

```
error:'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

what is the problem ?

as I said I was just wondering what is the differences both line

[pandas filtring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxsbj.png)

Comment: Could you add the result of df.head() so we can see your dataset. Seems like an error with datatypes

Comment: It seems to me that `df["Year of Release"]` is a `object` type data. you should change the datatype to int

Comment: `df.types.loc['Year of Release']` is not numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you more specific suggestions without knowing more about the dataset you're using, but I think this should solve your problem:

```
### remove non-digit characters from the "Year of Release" column
df["Year of Release"] = df["Year of Release"].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)

### convert "Year of Release" column to integer data type
df["Year of Release"] = df["Year of Release"].astype(int)

### filter the DataFrame
result = df[(df["Year of Release"] >= 1960) & (df["Year of Release"] <= 2000)][["Movie Name", "Year of Release"]]
```

Comment: also I add this line --- df["Year of Release"] = df["Year of Release"].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True) its working thank you

Comment: yeah, that's a great cleanup step! I will add this part in my answer too